# Android video recognition

Tags: java, android, video-processing, pattern-recognition

I tried to google in hope to find any Google Goggles alike tools/libraries that would somewhat allow the developer to recognize objects in a video.

I understand this is a complex topic.

Are there any libraries that would recognize shapes in a video? For instance detect if there are any squares in a given frame/video? I'm pretty sure Goggles can do that, but from what I researched it doesn't have an SDK to use.

**UPDATE**: [Recognizr](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/recognizr_facial_recognition_coming_to_android_phones.php) seems be a good example of a part of what I am trying to accomplish. But it's an application that was not released yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision) is a library that lots of folks use to base these styles of project off of. There's currently a beta-quality project for running the OpenCV code using the NDK on Android:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android

There are plenty of resources for OpenCV linked to from the wiki and the project page, and it's pretty easy to find samples for OpenCV floating around. But like you said, it's a pretty complex topic overall, and while the framework gives you a leg up on development there will still be plenty to layer in before you even have a working prototype.